# iOS: how to verify distribution certificates and provision files via command line?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

I'm building a script for IPA automated generation, I tried to import my certificate with:

```
security import certificatePath  -k loginKeychainPath -t priv -P certificatePassword
```

However, I found that it generated the IPA anyway even if I imported a wrong password or another entirely unrelated provision file.

How could I verify the certificate and provision file? Thanks.